# PHP From Input tag session issue

Tags: php, html, session

switch back different PHP pages and come back again to my registration page i want to display my previous entered value in input area. how to handle session as input tag value?. is there any mistake with my code?

```
<form method="post">
<input id="username" name="username" 
   required="required" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>" /></form>
```

Comment: add session_start(); at the top of the page

Comment: Make sure to add the missing semicolon after `$_SESSION['username']` . Besides that I don't see why this wouldn't work. Turn on error-reporting and show the error.

Comment: `username` has stored in `$_SESSION['username']`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you stored the POST-REQUEST?

example

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && strlen(trim($_POST['username']))>1)) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you set value to $_SESSION['username']?

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```